# std::map key value pairs not iterating in sequence

Tags: c++, iteration, stdmap

I am inserting key value pairs in a `std::map` as

```
key = //something;
value = //something;
demoMap[key] = value;
```

Printing the key and value here gives me correct results. However, when I iterate this map as:

```
for( std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it = demoMap.begin();
     it != demoMap.end(); it++ ) {
    std::cout << it->first + "," << it->second;
}
```

Using above iteration, I get the second key value pair printed before the first one. Why is it so? The first key value pair should be printed first since the iterator of the map is set to `begin()` for the map.

Comment: Since you do not show the data the you are storing or the order you fill the  map I can only guess that you are seeing that the map sorts by key but your filling of the map is not in key order.

Comment: Note that you don't print new line, or any separator between `second` and next `first`

Comment: std::map doesn't preserve the order of element insertion.  Maybe you want std::vector<std::tuple> ?

Comment: did you debug it yourself?

Comment: @nephtes Or simply `std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::string>>`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ah yes, forgot about std::pair.  Good call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `std::map` is not ordered by insertion order, but through ordering of the keys which is by default obtained with `operator<` on the keys.

For `std::string` the default `operator<` uses lexicographical ordering, so keys will be iterated in that order only.